# How to save multidimensional different array shapes

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know how to save multidimensional arrays of different shapes into an array if it was possible so that I could easily call the individual array. For example, the first array could be (1,100), the second could be (4,500), third maybe (1000,6).
This is the code:

```
#Function for the means of C
C_values = []


def Creation(data, h):
  Cmean = np.mean(data,axis=1).reshape(data.shape[0],1)
  S = C_values.append(Cmean)
  m = np.log2(h)
  for l in range(1,int(m)):
    r = 0                                                  
    size = h//(2**(l))                                                                                                                
    C = np.array(np.zeros(shape=(data.shape[0],2**l)))                                   
    for i in range(0,C.shape[0]):                                             
      for j in range(0,C.shape[1]):
        if j == 0:
          C[i,j] = (np.mean(data[i][j:j+size]))-C_values[l-1][i]
        elif j > 0:
          C[i,j] = (np.mean(data[i][(size*j):(size*j)+size]))-C_values[l-1][i]
        elif j==0 and l>1:
          C[i,j] = (np.mean(data[i][j:j+size]))-C_values[l-1][i][j]
        elif j==1 and l>1:
          C[i,j] = (np.mean(data[i][(size*j):(size*j)+size]))-C_values[l-1][i][j-1]
        elif j>1 and l>1:
          r+=1
          C[i,j] = (np.mean(data[i][(size*j):(size*j)+size]))-C_values[l-1][i][r]
    S = C_values.append(C)
  return C_values
```

I tried data with shape (4,15000) and this code worked. I could call out the individual arrays by typing C_values[0] and C_values[1]. However, when I tried another data with shape (8,15000) I got an error: **setting an array element with a sequence**. And the reference point is

```
C[i,j] = (np.mean(data[i][j:j+size]))-C_values[l-1][i]
```

Please I need help. Comments and corrections are welcome.

Comment: please add the numpy tag to your question

Comment: @feverdream, okay. I have done that.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I changed and added few things to the code.

```
#Function for the means of C
C_values = []


def Creation(data, h):
  Cmean = np.mean(data,axis=1).reshape(data.shape[0],1)
  S = C_values.append(Cmean)
  m = np.log2(h)
  for l in range(1,int(m)):                                        
    size = h//(2**(l))                                                                                                                
    C = np.array(np.zeros(shape=(data.shape[0],2**l)))                                   
    for i in range(0,C.shape[0]): 
      r = 0                                            
      for j in range(0,C.shape[1]):
        if j == 0 and l<= 1:
          C[i,j] = (np.mean(data[i][j:j+size]))-C_values[l-1][i]
        elif j > 0 and l<=1:
          C[i,j] = (np.mean(data[i][(size*j):(size*j)+size]))-C_values[l-1][i]
        elif j==0 and l>1:
          C[i,j] = (np.mean(data[i][j:j+size]))-C_values[l-1][i][j]
        elif j==1 and l>1:
          C[i,j] = (np.mean(data[i][(size*j):(size*j)+size]))-C_values[l-1][i][j-1]
        elif j>1 and l>1:
          if j%2 == 0:
            r+=1
          C[i,j] = (np.mean(data[i][(size*j):(size*j)+size]))-C_values[l-1][i][r]
    S = C_values.append(C)
  return C_values
```

The C_values stores all the multidimensional arrays.